# Adding Value and percentage to pie chart in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, charts

I have a asp pie chart in c# 
I know how to show percentage in the pie 
or to show value number

but how can I show both of them in the same pie chart

[image]

Comment: if you explain what you want, what do you mean by show both in same pie chart?

Comment: Or do you mean showing more than one section in pie, with legends to identify?

Comment: @KrunalPatil Iupdated my question, hope it will help you understand

Comment: Are you creating your charts directly from database, or you are processing the data and than displaying them on chart?

Comment: @KrunalPatil directly from the database

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach(DataPoint p in yourChart.Series["yourseries"].Points)
{
     p.Label="#PERCENT\n#VALX";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by fra9001 works fine.
It has to be said that the code should be writen on the prerendercomplete event.
In VB I used that:

```
Private Sub test2_PreRenderComplete(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.PreRenderComplete
    For Each p In Chart1.Series(0).Points
        p.Label = "#PERCENT\n#VALX"
    Next
End Sub
```